# Boot menu not showing, only sound

Tags: boot, usb

I originally had Windows 8 on my computer, then I changed to Ubuntu 14.04 for not some days ago. I did a complete installation and overwrote Windows 8. Now I need to dual boot with Kali Linux, so I fixed a bootable USB with Kali and inserted it. The USB was not detected on Asus advanced settings where I usually find my USB boots so I searches the settings and managed to "force" boot from the USB. My keyboard & mouse were disabled so I was unable to press install/do anything. I changed some settings in the boot menu and now I don't know what is going on!

I cannot come to the loading screen where it says "press F2 or del to enter bios". There are 3 beeps when I start my computer and then it loads with  a  black screen for 5 minutes and enter Ubuntu 14.04, as usual but MUCH longer time.

The problem is that I cannot enter BIOS nor do a regular boot with any OS on an USB. I think I changed a setting to boot via Windows something something and then it failed to boot!

Comment: When BIOS beeps abnormally it usually means you have a hardware problem, and not something that could have been caused by installing an OS. You should be able to search online for what those beep codes mean if you know which type of BIOS you have (AMI, Award, etc). If you edit your question and specify if those beeps are short or long beeps ("long" here means approximately one second, while "short" is more of a "bipp" type), then maybe someone here can help you find out.

Comment: I changed some boot settings in BIOS, as I wrote, and now it beeps  1 beep then wait 1 sec then beep 3 fast times. Everything is black screen, and sometimes now I am unable to enter the computer because it's just a black screen all the time. I got an Asus bios.